# Python doesn't load _fileio library

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have a problem, Python doesn't loads the dynamic c library _fileio

```
~ $ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Could not open PYTHONSTARTUP
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/sven/.pythonrc'
>>> import io
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/io.py", line 63, in <module>
    import _fileio
ImportError: No module named _fileio
>>> 

~ $ locate _fileio
/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_fileio.so 

~ $ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/lib/python2.6/
```

greetings Sven

Comment: What distribution? How did you install it (from source, repository, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this line in my zshrc file

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6
```

but ubuntu uses per default Python 2.7.1

As I deleted the line from above, the error message dissapeared.

Sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an environment issue, stemming from this line:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/sven/.pythonrc'
```

To solve this, find `.pythonrc` and make sure the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable in your `.bashrc` file points to this file location. If it is in fact correct, try using the hardcoded path to `/home/sven/.pythonrc` rather than something such as `~/.pythonrc`.

Also, if I remember right, `.pythonrc` should actually be a `*.py` file, but that might vary depending on the distribution.

Comment: I had this line in my zshrc file

    export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6

but ubuntu uses per default Python 2.7.1

As I deleted the line from above, the error message dissapeared.

Sorry, my fault.

Comment: Are you still not able to import `_fileio`?